# Error with SlickConfig and Guice configuration in my code

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, slick

I'm new in Scala/Play/Slick and I'm trying write API returner. But everything is right until I write this piece:

```
    package controllers

    import play.api.db.slick.DBAction
    import play.api.mvc.Controller
    import play.api.db.slick.DefaultSlickConfig


    object GroupController extends  Controller{
      def getSheduleOfGroup(group: String) = DBAction{
        request =>
          implicit val session = request.dbSession
          Ok(" ")
      }
    }`
```

---

It's my route for running:
GET     /:group                  controllers.GroupController.getSheduleOfGroup(group)

---

Other controller without slick and DBAction is running normally

Some of my error logs:

```
    [error] application - 

    ! @6p1lcei54 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/sdf] ->

    play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

    1) No implementation for play.api.db.slick.SlickConfig was bound.
      while locating play.api.db.slick.SlickConfig

    1 error]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:265) ~[play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:191) ~[play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at play.core.server.Server$class.logExceptionAndGetResult$1(Server.scala:50) [play-server_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]

    1) No implementation for play.api.db.slick.SlickConfig was bound.
      while locating play.api.db.slick.SlickConfig

    1 error
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1042) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
```

and build.sbt file

```
name := "TimetableAPI"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `timetableapi` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( jdbc , cache , ws   , specs2 % Test,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.9.0-M1",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34")

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify database configuration. For the version of play-slick you have configured in your build.sbt, look at the documentaion here https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/wiki/Usage and look for the configuration example near the bottom of the page.